Extracting values from a list/dictionary?
I'm very very new to python and am trying to build an algo trading program. I have reached a point where I cannot extract a value I need from an output that looks like this:
{'stat': 'Ok', 'values': [{'exch': 'NFO', 'token': '35013', 'tsym': 'BANKNIFTY27NOV24F', 'dname': 'BANKNIFTY NOV FUT', 'optt': 'XX', 'instname': 'FUTIDX', 'pp': '2', 'ls': '15', 'ti': '0.05'}, {'exch': 'NFO', 'token': '35025', 'tsym': 'BANKNIFTY24DEC24F', 'weekly': 'W4', 'dname': 'BANKNIFTY DEC FUT', 'optt': 'XX', 'instname': 'FUTIDX', 'pp': '2', 'ls': '15', 'ti': '0.05'}, {'exch': 'NFO', 'token': '35012', 'tsym': 'BANKNIFTY29JAN25F', 'dname': 'BANKNIFTY JAN FUT', 'optt': 'XX', 'instname': 'FUTIDX', 'pp': '2', 'ls': '15', 'ti': '0.05'}]}
I'm trying to extract the value of 'token' but cannot do it. I have only tried extracting the data with some method (not sure if that is the correct term to use here) itertools but obviously, it didn't work.
Can someone please help with this?

Please [edit] and add a [mre] to show what you've tried. How do you want the values extracted? Into a list or? You need to add more details.

Python dictionaries are a fundamental part of the language. You really need to familiarise yourself with them. I suggest: Getting started

load the dict as a variable "data" then extract the values for the key "values"
iterate over the resulting list to get each dict and getthe value for the key "token"
values = data["values"]

for item in values:
    print(item["token"])

which provides:
35013
35025
35012


It is the output of a function that returns the properties for a future, so the 'value" and, by extension, 'token' will always be there.
